# Is their a way to just write to the cache without querying in apollo client?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

### Preface:

With the addition of server-side components in react sometimes it makes sense to fetch some data on the server side,  but I would still like to use the apollo client cache it seems like it is a waste to try to fetch data that I already have available (*Passed down via props*)

### Question

Is there a way to just write to the cache without attempting to fetch the data

### Code:

```js
'use client'

import { useQuery, gql,  } from "@apollo/client";
import { Event as EventType } from '@/gql/index';

interface Props {
    events: EventType[];
}

const GET_EVENTS = gql`
    query Events {
    events {
    _id 
    createdBy
    name
    date
    description
        }
    }
`;

const WriteEventsCache: React.FC<Props> = ({ events }) => {

// Do I have to do this?
    const { data } = useQuery(GET_EVENTS, {
        
    });

// Or can i just do something like this
client.writeQuery({
  query: gql`
    query Events {
    events {
    _id 
    createdBy
    name
    date
    description
        }
    }
`;
  data: { // Contains the data to write
  },




    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default WriteEventsCache;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write directly to the cache with [cache.modify](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#using-cachemodify)

You can also query the cache without hitting the server by using a [cache-only](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#cache-only) `fetchPolicy`.